# Compute oracle not visible

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

the compute functions results are not visible. only total and count are visible

```
BREAK ON PET_ID SKIP 5
COMPUTE COUNT LABEL 'No. of Visits' OF VISIT_DATE ON PET_ID
COMPUTE AVG LABEL 'Avg Cost' OF BASIC_COST ON PET_ID
COMPUTE MIN LABEL 'Min Cost' OF BASIC_COST ON PET_ID
COMPUTE MAX LABEL 'Max Cost' OF BASIC_COST ON PET_ID
COMPUTE SUM LABEL 'Total Cost' OF BASIC_COST ON PET_ID
/
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. There is no question here...

Comment: There is, @Olaf, only if you knew something about Oracle's SQL Plus command line tool so that you could *recognize* it.

Comment: The extra formatting and tagging now makes it clearer, but there is still no question. Currently "correct" seems to be an appropriate reply. And stackoverflow is not only here to solve your immediate problem, but to serve as repository for others, that's why we ask for as much information as possible, in question form, not just a quick dump of a problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `COMPUTE` as separate commands (because only the last takes effect); put all of them into the single line, separated by space.

```
SQL> break on pet_id
SQL> compute count label 'No. of visits' avg label 'avg cost' min label 'min cost' max label 'max cost' sum label 'total cost' of basic_cost on pet_id
SQL> select * from pets order by pet_id;

    PET_ID PET_NAME   BASIC_COST
---------- ---------- ----------
        10 CLARK            2450
           KING             5000
           MILLER           1300
**********            ----------
avg cost              2916,66667
No. of vis                     3
min cost                    1300
max cost                    5000
total cost                  8750
        20 JONES            2975
           FORD             3000

    PET_ID PET_NAME   BASIC_COST
---------- ---------- ----------
        20 ADAMS            1100
           SMITH             800
           SCOTT            3000
**********            ----------
avg cost                    2175
No. of vis                     5
min cost                     800
max cost                    3000
total cost                 10875
        30 WARD             1250
           TURNER           1500

    PET_ID PET_NAME   BASIC_COST
---------- ---------- ----------
        30 ALLEN            1600
           JAMES             950
           BLAKE            2850
           MARTIN           1250
**********            ----------
avg cost              1566,66667
No. of vis                     6
min cost                     950
max cost                    2850
total cost                  9400

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```